# Why does adding my gem to a website not work?

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I created a gem `Helloword` with the command:

```
bundle gem helloword
```

[image]

I built the gem with the command:

```
gem build helloword.gemspec
```

I edited the `Gemfile` of my Rails app:

```
gem 'helloword', '0.1.0', path: '/Users/iloveyou/helloword'
```

and I installed the gem:

```
bundle install
```

I am using the gem in my page like:

```
<h1><%= hello_word_tag %></h1>
```

I get the result:

[image]

Why did adding my gem to the website not work?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

i Fixed:
Change:

```
 def hello_word_tag
    "Hello Word!!!"
  end
```

to:

```
 def self.hello_word_tag
    "Hello Word!!!"
  end
```

and call:

```
<h1><%= Helloword.hello_word_tag %></h1>
```

Answer (score 1):

Because you haven't called the module `Helloword`.

Comment: i try : <h1><%= Helloword.hello_word_tag %></h1> but it show error: undefined method `hello_word_tag' for Helloword:Module

Comment: That is because you have not defined `Helloword.hello_word_tag`. You only defined `Helloword#hello_word_tag`.

Comment: Nope. Read my comment above.

Comment: if use: <h1><%= Helloword#hello_word_tag %></h1>, occur syntax error

Comment: Of course it does. You need to do `Helloword.new.hello_word_tag`. It looks like you don't even know the difference between class methods and instance methods. You better learn the basics of the Ruby language before you go on to try to create a gem. It is too early for you.